# Is it possible to Auto-increment an id and reset to 1 depending on another id in Visual studio 2013 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Here's my example:

```
User_id  Listing_id
 1           1
 1           2
 1           3
 2           1
 2           2
 3           1
 3           2
 4           1
```

I thought this would be better than having a unique ids for every listing, but i read around and some were saying that its better to use a unique identifier for listing alone because its one less information than using, in my example user and listing id together as a primary key.

But that was back in 2009 and i wonder if anything is changed.....

So my question really is, is this possible? and if it is, is it advisable

Comment: I didn't understand anything. Can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do what you want using a trigger, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Just have a unique id for each row.  Then, if you want an incrementing number:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by id)
from table t;
```

You can do the enumeration when you need the value rather than on insert.

I am a strong advocate of integer, identity columns for tables.  Here are some reasons:

- A single column is more practical for foreign key relationships.
- Integers (of whatever size) are efficient for comparisons and indexes.
- Maintaining a column as you would like requires a lot of overhead, because you have to be sure there are no gaps, even for multiple simultaneous inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: thanks alot, yeah i think i'll take your advice and have two separate tables, one for User containing user_id and name etc, and one for listing containing listing_id, listing_title etc..... one question in terms of design that's still bugging me, should i have a User_Listing table that only contains User_id and Listing_id? and if yes how do i group the user_id with it's appropriate listing_id (sounds like a dumb question)?
Thanks for the help tho man

Comment: @MazinIbrahim . . . You want three tables:  `Users` for users.  `Listings` for listings, and `UserListings` as a junction table to connect the two.